# How to make the equivalent of @Ajax.DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a partial view in my MVC3/Razor app for paging a grid which works fairly well currently.  When I AJAXified it, I converted all the @Html.ActionLink calls to @Ajax.ActionLink.  Now I want to add a DropDownList, but @Html.DropDownList doesn't cause the AJAX section to post back, and there's no @Ajax.DropDownList.

What can I do to get this dropdown to post back on change?

**Edit:** By preference, something that I can write into my own @Ajax.DropDownList helper would be best.  I'm sure the jQuery-based solutions below work, and I'll use them if necessary, but I'm sure I'm going to want this functionality elsewhere, and I'd prefer to not have all these little scripts floating around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with - it was originally inspired by Darin's answer, but I took it in a completely different direction.

```
    public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(this AjaxHelper html, string action, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, AjaxOptions options, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectItems, IDictionary<string, object> listHtmlAttributes)
    {
        var url = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);

        // Wrap it in a form
        var formBuilder = new TagBuilder("form");


        //  build the <select> tag
        var listBuilder = new TagBuilder("select");
        if (listHtmlAttributes != null && listHtmlAttributes.Count > 0) listBuilder.MergeAttributes(listHtmlAttributes);
        StringBuilder optionHTML = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (SelectListItem item in selectItems)
        {
            var optionBuilder = new TagBuilder("option");
            optionBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", item.Value);
            optionBuilder.InnerHtml = item.Text;
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                optionBuilder.MergeAttribute("selected", "selected");
            }

            //optionBuilder.Attributes["onchange"] = "($this.form).attr('action', '" + url.Action(action, routeValues).Replace("___", item.Value) + "');$(this.form).submit();";
            optionHTML.Append(optionBuilder.ToString());
        }
        listBuilder.InnerHtml = optionHTML.ToString();
        listBuilder.Attributes["onchange"] = "$(this.form).attr('action', '" + url.Action(action, routeValues).Replace("___", "' + $(this).first('option:selected').val() + '") + "');$(this.form).submit();";
        formBuilder.InnerHtml = listBuilder.ToString();

        foreach (var ajaxOption in options.ToUnobtrusiveHtmlAttributes())
            formBuilder.MergeAttribute(ajaxOption.Key, ajaxOption.Value.ToString());
        string formHtml = formBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(formHtml);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a normal `Html.DropDownListFor` applying it some custom CSS class and then subscribe for the `.change` event and trigger the AJAX request manually:

```
$(function() {
    $('.someClassYouHaveAddedToYourDdl').change(function() {
        var page = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SomeActionResponsibleForPagination")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { page: page }, // The page parameter might need adapting
            success: function(result) {
                // TODO: here you could refresh the part of the DOM containing
                // the grid with the new results. Use $('.someSelector').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This definitely looks like it'd work, and I'll implement it if there isn't a better option, but I was hoping for something I could put into a HTML Helper.  I've edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: @Bobson, you would better externalize the code I have shown into a [custom jQuery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). You don't need to write HTML helpers as it already exists: `Html.DropDownListFor`. Once you have the jquery plugin you would simply attach it to your WebGrid.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can fire the change event like so, and then either submit the form or perform the desired AJAX post back to your desired route.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#dropDownList").change(function() {
        // your code here

     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Good evening! i rewrite certain functions in this way:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(this AjaxHelper html, 
   string action, 
   AjaxOptions options, 
   IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectItems, 
   IDictionary<string, object> listHtmlAttributes)
```

but i can't write working code with `HtmlAttributes`.  Here's my variant:

```
@Ajax.DropDownList("ApplSort", new AjaxOptions() { 
                         HttpMethod = "POST", 
                         InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,  
                         UpdateTargetId = "target", 
                         LoadingElementId = "AjaxSearch" }, 
   new[]
   {
      new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Заявки от новых к старым" },
      new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Заявки от старых к новым" }
   }, 
   new IDictionary<string, object>  { id = "DropDownListSort", @class = "chosen" }
)
```

or

```
@Ajax.DropDownList("ApplSort", new AjaxOptions() { 
                         HttpMethod = "POST", 
                         InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,  
                         UpdateTargetId = "target", 
                         LoadingElementId = "AjaxSearch" },
    new[]
    {
       new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Заявки от новых к старым" },
       new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Заявки от старых к новым" }
    }, 
    new  { id = "DropDownListSort", @class = "chosen" }
)
```

How can I write it correctly?

Problem is solved. Wrote two extensions, and it worked:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(this AjaxHelper html, string action, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, AjaxOptions options, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectItems, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return DropDownList(html, action, routeValues, options, selectItems, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    }

    public static MvcHtmlString DropDownList(this AjaxHelper html, string action, AjaxOptions options, IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectItems, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return DropDownList(html, action, options, selectItems, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
    }
```