# ASP.NET MVC - Refreshing DropDownLists into ViewModel without write DOM code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have a ViewModel into my application like this:

```
public class ItemViewModel {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string SelectedType { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Type> Types { get; set; }

    public string SelectedSubtype { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Subtype> Subtypes { get; set; }
}
```

I've created a View to exposes these properties:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedType,
    new SelectList(Model.Types, "ID", "Description"),
    "Select a type")

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSubtype,
    new SelectList(Model.Subtypes, "ID", "Description"),
    "Select a subtype")
```

Well, when I want to refresh my subtypes dropdownlist, I have to write a lot of DOM code to generate the new options.

```
$('#SelectedType').change(function() {
    $.get('/json/GetSubtypesFromType', { 'type': $(this).val() }, function(result) {

        var options = '';
        for (var count = 0; count < result.length; count++) {
            options += "<option value='" + result[count].ID + "'>" + result[count].Description + "</option>";
        }

        $('#SelectedSubtype').html(options);
    });
});
```

Is there a way to bind the new options to Subtypes enumerable into my `ViewModel` instead write this code for generate the options. I need to retrieve the new enumerable when I post my form, but I want to bind the new values into `ViewModel` collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Observation:** You are 'get'-ting values with AJAX and want the new values added to your DropDownList Helper.

**Suggestion1:** *Create a custom Ajax Drop Down List Helper.*

read this article on http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/421640/Creating-a-custom-AJAX-Helper

another good ref [How to make the equivalent of @Ajax.DropDownList?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206066/how-to-make-the-equivalent-of-ajax-dropdownlist)

particularly valuable ref
http://www.mikeyd.com.au/2009/08/22/dynamically-populate-a-selectdrop-down-list-using-aspnet-mvc-jquery-and-json/

**Suggestion 2:** *Use an action partial to create your dropdownlist*
Executed as `@Html.Action("{Action}", {Controller}", new { id = {param})`

or from jquery as `$('#dropdowndiv').load('/{Controller}/{Action}')`, action partials first call an action method, then render a partial view. This is ideal for cases where you want to dynamically create a *selectlist* on the fly

Comment: Thanks, Dave A. Both suggestions are good, and I'll try to implement the second one first. If I can't, the first solution help me also. Thanks!!!